# How to make a game while avoiding global variables?

Tags: python, variables, local

Just read that global variables are bad, which is shocking because I use them all the time. The way I'm making games right now is by making a function for each location in a game, like so.

```
def menu():
   #stuff

def game():
   #stuff

while True:
    if location=="menu":
        menu()
    #etc
```

And then I always use the `global` keyword at the top of each function. This way, if there's something that needs to be reset frequently, like a score, I can do it at the very top of the page, outside the game function. My question is, how is it possible to do things like that with only local variables? I can't do this.

```
def game():
    timer+=1
```

There wouldn't be a way I can initialize timer without making it a global variable. I have a feeling that the way I'm doing it is the "incorrect" way of making games. If so, then what is the "correct" way? By the way I have one python page for commonly used functions such as drawing or writing, and everything else is in a game python page.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be to create classes, and then create instances of those classes.

For example a `Menu` class, with various methods and attributes.

```
class Menu():
   ...

menu = Menu()
```

Avoiding global variables makes it usually easier to debug, as you keep track of the 'format' of your data.